# Permutation of string

Tags: c, string, permutation

I am trying to implement a code where i have to permute a string.Whenever i try to execute my code i get the following errors and warnings;

> 1.passing argument 1 of permute makes integer from pointer without a cast
>
> 2.expected char but argument is of type char *
>
> 3.conflicting type for permute

what might cause those errors in my program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void swap(char *first,char *second);
void permute(char a,int l,int r);

int main(){
   char str[] = "ABC";
   int size = strlen(str);
   permute(str,0,size-1);
   return 0;
}
void permute(char *a,int l,int r){
   if (l==r){
       printf("%s\n",a);
   }else{
       int i;
       for(i=l;i<=r;i++){
           swap((a+l),(a+i));
           permute(a,l+1,r);
           swap((a+l),(a+i));
       }
   }

}
void swap(char *first,char *second){
    char *temp;
    *temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = *temp;
}
```

Comment: i changed that,,,,but still the program doesn't work

Comment: Isn't this what you want for swap?                                                      void swap(char *first,char *second){
    char temp;
    temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
}

Comment: You should debug each of your fuctions one by one. Strlen already returns only number of characters. which would be 3 for "ABC", passing size-1 is already wrong. There would be other issues too, test your swap function separately as asked already

Comment: amongst other problems with the code, this prototype: `void permute(char a,int l,int r);` does not match the actual function signature: `void permute(char *a,int l,int r)`.   I.E. the prototype says the first parameter is a `char` however the actual function says the first parameter is a `pointer to char`

Comment: variable and parameter names should indicate content or usage (or better, both).  The names: `a`, `l`, `r` are meaningless even in the current context.

Comment: in the `swap()` function, the variable `char *temp`  is never set to a point to a known location,  so this kind of line: `*temp = *first;` is saving the character as some unknown location.   That is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest  `char temp;` (not a pointer, but an actual char holder) and modify the rest of the function body to match.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  It is also a good idea to separate functions via a pair of blank lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an error in your function prototype.  It's declared like this:

```
void permute(char a,int l,int r);
```

But defined like this:

```
void permute(char *a,int l,int r) {
```

Note that the type of the first argument does not match.  You need to change the prototype to match the definition.

Unrelated to that, your `swap` function is using a pointer `temp` that is being dereferenced without being set.  This is undefined behavior and will likely cause a core dump.

Since you're swapping characters here, you only need a `char`, not a `char *`.

```
void swap(char *first,char *second){
    char temp;
    temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
}
```

Comment: code stops working whthhout any warning or errors now :(

Comment: Thats because your length of string is shorter. Strlen already returns 3 for ABC, why -1? Debug your code please

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that your data type is char for function permute where you want it to be an array. You want to use the parameter char *a[]. Permute should be

```
void permute(char *a[], int l, int r)
```

Comment: While the error pointed out is correct, the solution isn't. Either its char *a or char a[].  But can't be both (answer originally wrote char *a[]) i.e. you are not passing a pointer to a char array. You are either passing a pointer to character (which is first element) (char *a) OR address of first element of an arary (char a[])